# Adding a list into a root list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set up classes to store data in my code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Email {
    public string User_Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Status {
    public string User_Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateTime {get; set; }
}

public class Collection_Detail {
    public string Bank_Name { get; set; }
    public string Acc_Name { get; set; }
    public string Acc_No { get; set; }
    public List<Status> return_Status { get; set; }
    public List<Email> email_Notification { get; set; }
}
```

I add data into a List of `Email`s

```
List<Email> email = new List<Email>();
email_Notifications.Add(new Email_Notification() {User_Email = 'toSender' , dateTime = '2020/10/10'});
```

And now, I want to put `Email` list into `'Collection_Detail'`. I tried by using

```
List <Collection_Detail> details = new List <Collection_Detail> ();
details.add(new Collection_Details() {});
```

However, I am getting an error.

> cannot intialize type with a collection initiaizer because it does not
> implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

1. Any idea how to put a list(s) into another list as a root list ? or
2. How do I implement 'IEnumerable' into code above ?
3. I tried to refer this [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netcore-2.1) but no luck.

Comment: You have a List of `Collection_Detail`, but you are adding a `Collection_DetailS`

Comment: For simple code I will recommend a [mre] in a clean solution with no reference to the solution you are working on. With that metric tons of mismatch name. It's hard to not rules out a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing but this should be as easy as:

```
// Create the list of email notifications
List<Email> emails = new List<Email>();
emails.Add(new Email_Notification() {User_Email = 'toSender' , dateTime = '2020/10/10'});

// Create the list of collection detail
List <Collection_Detail> details = new List <Collection_Detail> ();
details.Add(new Collection_Detail() 
{
    email_Notification = emails
});
```

There were a number of variable names and class names which did not match in your code. Hopefully I've caught all errors in the above example.

The one I've not corrected is setting a `DateTime` instance to a string - that wont work but I assume you already know that and how to fix it.